# Transferring one datagridview data to another datagridview in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

Issue: Moving multiple rows and columns from one datagridview(non-data bound) to another datagridview and then displaying the second datagridview rows from another form which is data bound.

Developing platform : VB.NET 2008

Issue description:

- I have some rows and columns in another form's datagridview which is now populated from a local database that is now connected in my application.
- Having an error in EncodingCompleteDataSet inside the Update argument, which says 'Error 1 'EncodingCompleteDataSet' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.'
- Where would I insert `anotherForm.Show()` in the following code?

Issue Code:

```
Dim dr = DirectCast(DataGridViewX1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row
frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataSet.Tables("EncodingComplete").ImportRow(dr)
EncodingCompleteDataSetTableAdapters.EncodingCompleteTableAdapter.Update(EncodingCompleteDataSet, "EncodingComplete")
```

Regards,
CodingSource

***EDIT: For Jason Faulkner***

Code:

```
For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewX1.Columns
        frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.Columns.Add(DirectCast(Col.Clone, DataGridViewColumn))
    Next
    frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.Rows.Add(DataGridViewX1.Rows(0).Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.Value).ToArray)
```

Your code (which I altered a little):

```
Dim table As DataTable = DirectCast(frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.DataSource, DataView).Table

    ' Add row 0 to the DataGridViewX1 grid to the table.
    ' This assumes the schema/column names are the same between the two.
    Dim addRow As DataRow = table.NewRow
    For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewX1.Columns
        addRow(Col.Clone) = frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.Rows(0).Cells(Col.Clone).Value
    Next

    ' Add the copied row values to the table.
    ' Once we do this, it should appear in the EncodingCompleteDataGridView.
    table.Rows.Add(addRow)
```

But I'm having an error in `table As DataTable = DirectCast(frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.DataSource, DataView).Table`which says

> InvalidCastException was unhandled: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.

Comment: You drastically edited your question after an answer was already posted.

Comment: Sir, I already copied your code (with comments like Pull Source Data, etc.) and pasted it on my code. I have an error on "Dim table As DataTable = DirectCast(frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.DataSource, DataView).Table" which says "InvalidCastException was unhandled:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataView'. "

Comment: My code is the following: 
' Pull the source data.
        Dim table As DataTable = DirectCast(frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.DataSource, DataView).Table

        ' Add row 0 to the DataGridViewX1 grid to the table.
        ' This assumes the schema/column names are the same between the two.
        Dim addRow As DataRow = table.NewRow
        For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewX1.Columns
            addRow(Col.Clone) = frmEncodeDatabase.EncodingCompleteDataGridView.Rows(0).Cells(Col.Clone).Value
        Next

       
        table.Rows.Add(addRow)

Comment: As noted above, you drastically altered your question after my answer was posted. After your edit, my answer is completely irrelevant to what you have posted. Regarding the error, you would need to post more details as to _how_ it is databound. I made an assumption based on what your _original_ question was.

Comment: @Jason Faulkner edited the post for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'This is your new DataGridView

 Dim grdNew As New DataGridView



'This adds the row to your newDataGridView

    For Each item In Me.DataGridView1.Rows

        grdNew.Rows.Add(item)

    Next
```

Comment: However, I don't use the grdNew because I have an existing DataGridView that is data-bounded (and it is from another form) so your grdNew.Rows.Add(item) will not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sir I don't need the grdNew because I already a dgv that is data-bounded. What is the code for transferring rows from dgv(original) that is non-data bound to this data-bounded dgv...and clearing the original dgv.

Comment: it could be any name that is just a name I declared it could be any name